# Using sysfs_notify_dirent() correctly

Tags: c, linux-kernel, driver, sysfs

I've some trouble understanding how to use `sysfs_notify_dirent()` correctly. Basically, I'm writing a device driver, and I need one of the `sysfs` attributes exported by the driver to be "pollable" from user-space. Since I know when new data will be available from the device's ISR (that is an atomic context) for what I've understood, I must use `sysfs_notify_dirent()` instead of `sysfs_notify()`. However, I'm struggling to find any documentation or example on the subject. Could please someone point me to an example that shows how to use correctly `sysfs_notify_dirent()` or to some useful documentation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with this same problem. I was using `sysfs_notify()` succesfully, but needed to change it to `sysfs_notify_dirent()` to be able to use it within a hrtimer callback. I was able to figure it out, so I wanted to share it.

The thing is `sysfs_notify_dirent()` requires the kernfs_node that corresponds to the `sysfs` attribute you want to notify changes of. While with `sysfs_notify()` you need to pass the device kobj, the subdirectory name (or NULL if there is no subdirectory) and the attribute name. The question is: how do you find the kernfs_node of the attribute?

The `struct kobject` has a member `struct kernfs_node *sd` which is a pointer to the kernfs_node that corresponds to the kobj directory path.

So from your device kobject you already have the kernfs_node of your sysfs device's root directory. With it you need to obtain your attribute's kernfs_node using the function `sysfs_get_dirent()` to which you need to pass the kernfs_node and the name of the attribute or subdirectory you want the kernfs_node of.

Let's see a small example. Say your device kobject pointer is `mykobj` and it's name is `"mydevice"` and you have a subdirectory called `"mysubdir"` and an attribute `"myattr"`. This is how you get the kernfs_node of the subdirectory and the attribute:

```
/* This is our main kernfs_node */
struct kernfs_node *mydevice_kn = mykobj->sd;
/* This is our subdirectory kernfs_node */
/* We get the mydevice_kn child node thats named "mysubdir" */
struct kernfs_node *mysubdir_kn = sysfs_get_dirent(mydevice_kn, "mysubdir");
/* This is our attribute kernfs_node */
/* We get the mysubdir_kn child node thats named "myattr" */
struct kernfs_node *myattr_kn = sysfs_get_dirent(mysubdir_kn, "myattr");
```

Once you have the kernfs_node of your desired attribute, you can pass it to your `sysfs_notify_dirent()` function. If you don't have a subdirectory, then you just search for the node of the attribute directly.